# Xcodeで、Buttonでactionでなくてoutletで紐付けしてしまってビルドでのエラー

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

以下の5で困っています。

1. XcodeでIBを使い、ButtonをStoryboardに配置して
2. 紐付けするときに、actionでなくて、誤ってoutletで紐付けしてしまう
3. ビルド(Cmd+r)すると問題なく実行される
4. Cmd+zで戻ってビルド(Cmd+r)
5. [困りポイント]`Thread1: signal SIGABRT`が出てしまう

Xcodeはversion6.4でswiftで作っています。
iOSシミュレーターでReset contents and settings...を実行しても特に変化はないです。

不明な点は、
a.4でCmd+zで前の状態にもどってビルドが通るはずなのに、なぜ通らないのか。
 Buttonでoutletで紐付けするのはNGということでしょうか?
 今回は誤って紐付けしてしまいましたが、Labelなどと同じようにoutletを使いたい時もあるのかなと。

よろしくお願いします。

----- コメントから転記 -----
エラーログ

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myButton.'

----- ここまで -----

9/12 22:48 追記
どうやら、紐付けが残っていたようです↓で言うと MyButton。これをdeleteしたら、無事動きました。cmd*zの回数が足りなかったのですかね。。。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `signal SIGABRT`だけでは、エラーの内容がわかりません。
アプリが落ちた場合は`Terminating app due to uncaught exception`とログに出ているので、それ以降のログを貼っていただけると回答を得られやすいかと思います。

Comment: こんなログが出ています。何が原因なのでしょうか。。。2015-09-12 22:41:23.840 sample09122214[13539:184079] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<sample09122214.ViewController 0x7fb233c20390> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myButton.'

Comment: StoryBoard上で`myButton`をCtrl+クリックして`Referencing Outlets`に接続されているOutletがありますので、✖ボタンを押して削除してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます、無事に動きました。しかし、これはどういう背景なのでしょうか?なんで動いてなかったのかと、この対応がどういう意味があったのでしょうか?

Comment: Storyboard上のオブジェクト（インスタンス）間の関係と、プログラムコード上のオブジェクト間の関係が一致していないとダメという、けっこう単純な話です。「Xcodeがそこらへん、うまくやってくれてるんじゃないの？」と思われがちですが、そうでもないんですよ。プログラマたるもの、自分のプログラムには他人任せ（ソフト任せ）にせず、責任持ちましょう。

Answer (score 2):

ちょうどMAC触ってたので画像を踏まえて回答させていただきます。

> a.4でCmd+zで前の状態にもどってビルドが通るはずなのに、なぜ通らないのか。

こちらでも試してみたところ、
IBOutletやIBActionの変更を元に戻すには、StoryBoard上でCmd+zすれば元に戻せました。
コードペインをアクティブにしてCmd+zしてもStoryBoardファイルには影響がないようです。

> Buttonでoutletで紐付けするのはNGということでしょうか?

全くNGではありません。
むしろ必要な手順であって、UI部品とコードを対応させる行為がIBOutletです。

---

それで解決方法なんですが、推測で書かせていただきます。
XCodeのログに`unrecognized selector sent to instance`と出ていますでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像について説明させていただくと、
* UIButtonをIBOutletで`button`として定義しています。
* UIButtonのActionメソッドとして、`aaa`を定義しています。

この状態でアプリを起動し、buttonを押下すると`signal SIGABRT`が発生します。
ログは以下のとおりです。

```
2015-09-12 10:49:59.041 16535[1319:25886] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_6535.ViewController onButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee70d65ef0'
```

なぜエラーが発生するかと言いますと、UIButtonには`onButtonTapped:`が定義されているものの、ViewControllerクラスに`onButtonTapped:`が存在しないためです。

※上記の画像の様に、存在しないIBActionの定義が残っていてはダメ

Ctrlキーを押しながら対象のUI部品をクリックし、接続一覧（黒いポップアップ画面）を表示したら、不要な接続が残っていないか確認してみてください。

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instanceとは出ていませんでした、、、何卒よろしくお願いします